# Evaluating a limit involving fractions and logarithms

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I am trying to evaluate the following limit. Let $0 < \alpha < \infty$. Then

$\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\log(k)}{\log\left[(k+1)^\alpha(k)^{\alpha}\right]-\log\left[(k+1)^{\alpha}-k^{\alpha}\right]} &=
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\log(k)}{\alpha \log(k+1)+\alpha \log(k)-\log\left[(k+1)^{\alpha}-k^{\alpha}\right]} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha \frac{\log(k+1)}{\log(k)}+\alpha -\frac{\log\left[(k+1)^{\alpha}-k^{\alpha}\right]}{\log(k)}}
\end{align*}$

But where can I go from here?

Comment: have you tried Bernoulli L'hospital?

Comment: Im not sure how to use them in this case, sorry